# Find all the files of a specific extension and put them to a rar or zip

Tags: windows, batch-file

i want to find all the *.pdf files(including the pdf with the same name)for all 3 of my partitions C,D and F and put them into a .rar or .zip.when i started i wanted to just copy the pdf into a file but i realised it wasnt enough for what i wanted.can anyone give me any pointers?I had writen this

```
mkdir d:\test

mkdir f:\test1

chcp 65001

XCOPY C:*.pdf D:test /S /H

XCOPY F:*.pdf D:test /S /H

XCOPY D:*.pdf F:test1 /S /H

copy f:\test1 d:\test\kra\
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have installed `WinRAR`or a similar pack program:

```
for %%i in (c: d: f:) do for /f "delims=" %%j in ('dir /s /a-d /b %%i\*.pdf') do "C:\Program Files\WinRAR\Rar.exe" a myarchive "%%~j"
```

Comment: Hey mate i do have winrar in the folder C:\Program Files\WinRAR\Rar.exe the thing is i dont get what you have written and as it is it doesnt run.also where it will make the rar?

Comment: made an edit concerning your path to WinRar.

Comment: i made this 
for %%i in (c: d: f:) do for /f "delims=" %%j in ('dir /s /a-d /b %%i\*.srt') do "C:\Program Files\WinRAR\rar.exe" a d:\test.rar "%%~j" 
the problems is for example i checked the srt files i had 23 in the pc in the rar i have only 21 meaning i lose 2

Comment: Sorry, can't verify this here. It does work for me.

Comment: It seems like my pc is the problem i have problems with other programs as well after i deleted some srt files for example the computers was finding 17 your program 18 the weird thing is i found the 18th srt and after i double clic it it was opening ok i ll format my pc this weekend and i l try again as it seems to have some problems.once again thank you for the help :)

Comment: I tried to my girlfriends pc still the same problem (we both have win 7 64bit) when i press the windows key + E and i go top right and i type *.jpg for example in c and in d drives the total i get in her pc is lets say 3000 i run the program like you said 
for %%i in (c: d:) do for /f "delims=" %%j in ('dir /s /a-d /b %%i\*.jpg') do "C:\Program Files\WinRAR\Rar.exe" a d:\test.rar "%%~j"
and i find less than 3000 jpg

Comment: Is it possible the path to be too big and because of that not to copy it?

Comment: How long is it?

Comment: The path with the name it can be easily more than 40 characters in some cases i think its over 50

Comment: What OS (XP, win7, ..)?

Comment: win7 64bit fully updated

Comment: The command line length should not be a problem for cmd in win7, but it might be an issue for rar.exe. I don't know. You can try this with shorter paths, eg. `for %%i in ("c:\documents" "d:\documents" "f:\documents") ...`.

Comment: Ok mate thank you a lot for your info and help :)